# Unable to handel missing value in time series plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create time series graph using following sample code but it plots noting when I put **'nan'** for missing value but it works fine if no missing values in between

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot   
import numpy as np   
import datetime 

date= [[2014,01,01], [2014,02,02], [2014,03,01], [2014,04,01],   [2014,05,21]]

for i in range (len(date)):

   dtf.append(datetime.date(int(datet[i][1]),int(datet[i][1]),int(datet[i][2])).toordinal())    

days= np.array(dtf)

value =[ nan  nan  35  nan  25]  #not working

# work fine  value =[ 20  21  35  24  25]

# not working value =[ 20  21  35  nan  25] its joins line upto 35 only

ax.plot_date(x=days, y=value, fmt="r-")
plot.show()
```

plot should be break at missing value and continue with next value
please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

A line connects two points. If one of the two points is `nan` it cannot be plotted, hence the line between a point and `nan` cannot be drawn.
Plotting an array with `nan` values will therefore only show lines, where both points are present. 
This is fundamental logic and would occur even if trying to plot the data with pen and paper.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan
y = [2,3,2,nan,2,3,nan,3,nan,4,3,nan,2,1]
x = np.arange(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, marker="o")
ax.grid()
ax.set_xticks(x)
for i in x:
    if np.isnan(y[i]):
        ax.text(i, 1.4, "nan", ha="center", rotation=90, fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]